# Fetching the unique signing id

Tags: jmeter

My application uses a signing Id which is similar to session Id.but unique  signing Id is generated by system at the time of requesting the page only and not before that.Is it possible to fetch it?

Comment: Yes, if it is present in response (header, body) of a request. From what you are saying, I think ID is not used for signing in, but it is used for later requests. Then it should be present in response of sign in page or cookie. fetch it from there and use it.

Comment: It was a web service call and I have fetched the response using regular expression extractor.